# Replace all occurrences of character except in the beginning of string (Regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get rid of all minuses/dashes in a string number, except the first occurrence. After fiddling with Regex (JavaScript) for half an hour, still no results. Does anyone know the fix?

Given:

> -123-45-6

Expected:

> -123456

Given:

> 789-1-0

Expected:

> 78910

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one will do as well(it means dashes not at the beginning of the string):

```
(?!^)-
```

Example:

```
text = "-123-45-6".replace(/(?!^)-/g, "");
```

Comment: This is a lifesaver to me. Thanks for sharing.
Now, instead of a dash, I want to replace a string. I want my matching to be case insensitive. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution :

```
s = s.replace(/(.)-/g,'$1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Jutr try with:

```
'-123-45-6'.replace(/(\d)-/g, '$1');
```